# Access denied when using webform submissions email link

Tags: webforms, emails

Interim admin here- no experience- just trying to keep the wheels turning until a new hire made. Drupal 7.43.

Site has "contact us" form implemented as a webform, with email notification to certain addresses, who get email of the form:

> Submitted on Monday, July 18, 2016 - 4:48pm Submitted by anonymous user: IP.IP.IP.IP Submitted values are: Full Name Test2 Email test2@example.com Message This is an example The results of this submission may be viewed at: http://thenameofthesite.com/node/XXXXX/submission/YYYYY

where XXX and YYY are ids.

Users receiving the email complaining that clicking on the link gives a page on the site
with:

> Access denied
>   You are not authorized to access this page.

In the admin for the Webform contact form, under Access control, anonymous user is checked for both "View any webform content" and "View own Webform content".

Users are claiming this worked before, and I don't have the experience to gainsay them. Any suggestions on what else I can try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those permissions are for viewing the webform itself - you would need to set permissions to view/edit/delete the submissions.  You can find these settings under "Webform" at `/admin/people/permissions`